# Hazelcast IMap.values() and IMap.values(Predicate) give inconsistent values

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a very simple requirement to get All values stored in the IMap.   I have a server and client on the same box (no cluster just one instance of server and one instance of the client).

Server start:

```
Config config = new Config();
NetworkConfig network = config.getNetworkConfig();
JoinConfig join = network.getJoin();
join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled( false );
join.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled( false );
join.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Client start:

```
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1");
    HazelcastClient hazelIns = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    IMap<String,DeviceStatus> map = hazelIns.getMap("map");
```

Query:

```
class DeviceStatus{
String name;
String status;
DeviceStatus(String name,String status){
    this.name=name;
    this.status= status;
}

// PUT ALL OBJECTS

for(int i =0;i<1000;i++){
    DeviceStatus status = new DeviceStatus("Device"+i,"UP");
    map.put(status.getName(),status);
}

for(int i=0; i< 10000; i++){
    List<DeviceStatus> list = (List<DeviceStatus>)hazelIns.getMap("map").values();
    if(list.size() != 1000){
        System.out.println("ALL SIZE "+ list.size());
    }
    String sql = "name ilike %D%";
    List<DeviceStatus> list1 = hazelIns.getMap("map").values( new SqlPredicate( sql ));
    if(list1.size() != 1000){
        System.out.println("SQL SIZE "+ list1.size());
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Hazelcast version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting size miss-match size() sometimes from 1 to 1000 but I get 1000 size for majority of time. There is NO near-realtime cache.  Why there is an inconsistent result set for both SQL and total size? Just FYI, cache key is updated in the background but never removed.

Any pointer is would be a great help!

**Updated:**
Background update in a separate thread:

```
run(){
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        DeviceStatus status = new DeviceStatus("Device"+i,"DOWN");
        map.put(status.getName(),status);
}
```

Thanks,
Bhavesh

Comment: Can you provide an example for "_cache key is updated in the background_".  please ? The original code doesn't show any error for me. If other threads or processes update the data it could be an explanation, but it depends what they update.

Comment: @NeilStevenson, I have updated the background thread which just marks status up or down but does not remove.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't go wrong for me. Are you able to post a complete example ? I've filled in some omitted bits (such as how and when is the runnable run), and if I've done it a different way then that might be hiding the reason.

Comment: I got the original issue.  I think the issue was SQL predicate was changing based on Data being changed in the background.  @NeilStevenson thanks for checking.